# Compare different dicts for specific key value pair in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I need to compare keys and values in multiple dictionaries in python. There are similar questions posted but for my specific problem they are insufficient.  I'm getting syntax errors which I can't seem to understand.

My code is trying to compare dict keys and values between five different dicts.  I need to return the ones that are 100% the same between them and add those into a 'common' dict, `comm_one`:

```
comm_one = {}
for k, v in dot_105.items():
    if k, v in dot_110.items() and k, v in dot_81.items() and k, v in dot_82.items() and k, v in dot_100.items():
        comm_one[k] = v

    elif k, v not in dot_110.items() and k, v not in dot_81.items() and k, v not in dot_82.items() and k, v not in dot_100.items():
        print(k, v,' is only in dot_105.')
```

What's the proper syntax to loop through all values in all dicts?  If there is a question that answers this that I may have missed, I'd appreciate a link to it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: put `k,v` in parenthesis: `if (k,v) in ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
comm_one = {}

for key,value in dot_105.items():
    containing = [key in d and d[key]==value for d in (dot_110, dot_81, dot_82, dot_100)]
    if all(containing):
        comm_one[key] = value
    elif not any(containing):
        print(key, value,' is only in dot_105.')
```

Comment: Why did you revert the edit? This doesn't follow OP's logic. Your `else` is executed whenever the key/value pair doesn't appear in ALL dicts, while it should only be executed if the pair appears in EXACTLY ONE dict.

Comment: Can you explain what `d` is doing here?

Comment: Sure, we iterate through all of you dictionaries and strore current dict in that variable. You can read about this technique here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great solution. Is there anything between `all` or `any` which does 'some'? In other words, can I say "If key/value is in `some` dicts, return those values and whichever dicts they're in"?

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion, How about using Set Data structures to return the intersected data

From Python version 2.6 on you can use multiple arguments to set.intersection(), like

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

`intersected_data = set.intersection(dot_105.iteritems(),dot_110.iteritems() ,dot_81.iteritems(), dot_82.iteritems(), dot_100.iteritems()` )